# Creating a very flexible TOC with beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

To manage TOC in bearmer I normally use these codes:

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
\frame<beamer>{ 
\frametitle{Table of Contents}   
\tableofcontents[currentsection,subsections] 
 }
  }
\begin{frame}{Table of Contents}
\pdfbookmark[0]{Contents}{toc}
\tableofcontents{}
\end{frame}
```

I came across this [presentation](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/useR2010hpcTutorial.pdf). This have TOC for sections only in two columns and then at the start of each section it has TOC for the section and subsections (please have a look on this nice presentation).

I wonder how to get such TOC and and color scheme for this WARSAW theme. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I found that to get this beamer theme this code was used:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
}
```

Comment: Rather than edit the question to include an answer, please post your own answer below. It can then receive votes, and after 48 hours you can accept it as correct. This keeps the Q&A structure of TeX.sx clean.

Comment: @JosephWright: This is just a partial solution. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [multicol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package to switch to two-column mode for the ToCs; the color for certain parts can be changed by setting the appropriate template or color template. A little example with two-column ToCs and with a variation of the color for the sections in the upper navigation bar, and the sections in the partial ToCs at the beginning of each section:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multicol}

\colorlet{mycolor}{orange!80!black}% change this color to suit your needs

\title[Intro. to High-Perf. Computing ]{Introduction to\\ High-Performance Computing with R\\
\small Tutorial at \textit{useR! 201}}
\author{The Author}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
  \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=mycolor}
  \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc shaded}{fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=mycolor}
  \frame<beamer>{\begin{multicols}{2}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}  
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsections]
\end{multicols} 
 }
}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{white!70!black}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}{\color{white!70!black}\insertsubsectionhead}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section[]{Motivation}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Some title1}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Some title2}Test\end{frame}

\section[Tools]{Automation and Scripting}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Littler}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Rscript}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section[Measure]{Measuring and Profiling}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{RProf}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{RProfmem}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection[Profiling]{Profiling Compiled Code}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Sumary}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section[Faster]{Speeding up}
\subsection[Vec]{Vectorisation}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection[Ra]{Just-in-time compilation}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{BLAS}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{GPUs}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Summary}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Multiple columns TOC worked. Thanks. What about other things?

Comment: @MYaseen208: see my updated answer.

Comment: In the linked presentation, TOC only shows the sections for the specific section.

Comment: @MYaseen208: You can use the option `hideothersubsections` in the `\tableofcontents` options to only display the subsections in the current section. For more information about the different styles, see section "Adding a table of contents" (10.5 in my version) in the beamer manual, which usually goes under the name `beameruserguide.pdf`

Comment: @fabikw: Thanks for your comment. I'd appreciate if you have a quick look on the linked presentation and come up with an answer with solution. I'm trying to have same color scheme and same TOC style. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: see again my updated answer. Change the definition of `mycolor`, according to your needs.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for your help in past. Now I'm facing one problem with this TOC style. With many section and subsections the navigating bar becomes over crowded. Could you help me to show only 3 sections and 3 subsections [as in your this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54956/4821). Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is the closer I could get, building on Gonzalo's answer. Notice the `hideothersubsections` as well as the `beamertemplate`. I couldn't make it so that subsections doesn't go over the other column.

```
\documentclass    [10pt, compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{multicol}

\colorlet{mycolor}{orange!80!black}% change this color to suit your needs

\title[Intro. to High-Perf. Computing ]{Introduction to\\ High-Performance Computing with R\\
\small Tutorial at \textit{useR! 201}}
\author{The Author}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
  \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=mycolor}
  \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc shaded}{fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=mycolor}
  \setbeamertemplate{subsections in toc}[circle]
  \frame<beamer>{\begin{multicols}{2}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}  
  \tableofcontents[currentsection,subsections,hideothersubsections]
\end{multicols} 
 }
}

\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{\color{white!70!black}\insertsectionhead}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in head/foot}{fg=mycolor}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in head/foot shaded}{\color{white!70!black}\insertsubsectionhead}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section[]{Motivation}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Some title1}Test\end{frame}
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Some title2}Test\end{frame}

\section[Tools]{Automation and Scripting}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Littler}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Rscript}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section[Measure]{Measuring and Profiling}
\subsection{Overview}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{RProf}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{RProfmem}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection[Profiling]{Profiling Compiled Code}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Sumary}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\section[Faster]{Speeding up}
\subsection[Vec]{Vectorisation}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection[Ra]{Just-in-time compilation}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{BLAS}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{GPUs}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}
\subsection{Summary}
\begin{frame}Test\end{frame}

\end{document}
```