# How to reduce the navigation space size in beamer?

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am preparing slides/presentations of my research work in LaTeX beamer Warsaw theme. As my thesis presentation contains too many sections (which I don't want to reduce it), the final pdf output is such that in order to display all the sections in navigation section, nearly 40 percent of the presentation is getting used. This gives very less space for the content area. [image: Figure showing the navigation area occupied by the section contents]

I tried "Only 3 items in navigation bar" [enter link description here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54950/only-3-items-in-navigation-bar-is-that-possible).

But that resulted like this. [image: Only 3 times in navigation bar]

But my intention of reducing the navigation space to display the sections is not achieved. In this case also, the space/area for the presentation remain the same.

How can I achieve say, 3 items in navigation bar but reduced space in navigation bar?

I have lots of figures/diagrams/tables in my presentation.

Thanks in advance for your guidance/help

Comment: Have you seen this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205143/18228?

Comment: Yes Sir, Now I tried. The Sections and Subsections scrolls down as we move ahead of the presentation. But still, the navigation bar space once again remains the same. Each slide show 4 sections in navigation bar (with unnecessary space between the two section display)

Comment: But the answer (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/205249/18228) seems to solve exactly your problem