# How to show subsubsection in TOC [Beamer]

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, sectioning

I want to show subsubsection level in the TOC. But, beamer only show me at subsection.

I do not know how to active/show this level, I have tried:

```
\settocdepth{3} or \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
```

but, it does not work.

The code that I am working with is:

```
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\AtBeginSubSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,currentsubsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
```

The complete code that I am working with is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=pdftex,svgnames,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}
\usepackage[final]{movie15}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\useoutertheme{split}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Darmstadt}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}[split]
  \usefonttheme{serif}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % mfc para permitir introducir comando     /DH
\usepackage{times}
\title[CARMEN] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Collaborative Adaptive Robot for Mobility ENhancement}
\author[PhD dissertation] % (optional, use only with lots of authors)
{Cristina Urdiales Garc\'ia}
\institute%[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  KMLg\\
  Universidad Politecnica de Catalunya
}
\date[PhD dissertation] % (optional)
{26th November 2010 / PhD dissertation}
\subject{PhD dissertation}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}            

\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,currentsubsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,currentsubsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
\AtBeginSubSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,currentsubsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{center}
  \includegraphics [width =.3\textwidth ]{logos.jpg}
 \end{center}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Thesis' framework}
    
\subsubsection{pepe}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}%{Subtitles are optional.}
\begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{T1_statistic.jpg} \\
     \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{wheelchair.jpg}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Increase of motor impaired people in the western world\footnote{MOVEMENT: IST-2002-2.3.2.10 (FP6)}}
                \begin{itemize}
                 \item 31\% of the male population and 52\% of the female aged 75-84 report mobility problems
                  \item 1\% of the population in Europe (7.1M people) is in need of a wheelchair
                  \item Up to 60\% of these people may be assisted by a power wheelchair and an additional 20-25\% could be accommodated by more intelligent devices. 
               \end{itemize}
         \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. (From [beamer-highlighting-subsubsections-in-toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/231147/161015))

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[unknownkeysallowed,xcolor=pdftex,svgnames,dvipsnames,table]{beamer}

\usepackage{multicol}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage[final]{media9} % media15 is obsolete <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\useoutertheme{split}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Darmstadt}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[split]
    \usefonttheme{serif}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % mfc para permitir introducir comando     /DH
\usepackage{times}
\title[CARMEN] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{Collaborative Adaptive Robot for Mobility ENhancement}
\author[PhD dissertation] % (optional, use only with lots of authors)
{Cristina Urdiales Garc\'ia}
\institute%[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
    KMLg\\
    Universidad Politecnica de Catalunya
}
\date[PhD dissertation] % (optional)
{26th November 2010 / PhD dissertation}
\subject{PhD dissertation}

\colorlet{maincolor}{green!50!blue}% choose your color
    %%******************************************************************
%% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231128/beamer-highlighting-subsubsections-in-toc
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
    \setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=maincolor}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc shaded}{fg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in toc}{fg=maincolor}
    \setbeamercolor{subsubsection in toc shaded}{fg=black}
    \setbeamercolor{subsubsection in toc}{fg=maincolor}
    \frame<beamer>{\begin{multicols}{2}
            \frametitle{We are here}
            \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}  
            \tableofcontents[
            sectionstyle=show/shaded,
            subsectionstyle=show/show/shaded,
            subsubsectionstyle=show/show/show/shaded
            ]
        \end{multicols} 
    }
}
    %%******************************************************************

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics [width =.3\textwidth ]{example-grid-100x100pt}
    \end{center}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}  

\subsection{Thesis' framework}

\subsubsection{pepe}

\begin{frame}{Motivation}%{Subtitles are optional.}
\begin{columns}[c]
    \begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-a} \\
        \bigskip
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{Increase of motor impaired people in the western world\footnote{MOVEMENT: IST-2002-2.3.2.10 (FP6)}}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item 31\% of the male population and 52\% of the female aged 75-84 report mobility problems
                \item 1\% of the population in Europe (7.1M people) is in need of a wheelchair
                \item Up to 60\% of these people may be assisted by a power wheelchair and an additional 20-25\% could be accommodated by more intelligent devices. 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{block}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{The work}

\subsection{The budget}

\subsubsection{manuel}

\begin{frame}{The work}%{Subtitles are optional.}
    TO BE DONE
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Do not miss [why-are-beamer-subsubsections-evil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118478/why-are-beamer-subsubsections-evil)